# How to change grid tab style in peoplesoft

Tags: tabs, grid, styles, peoplesoft

My page is having grid which contain two tabs (tab sepaprtor). I need to make some color differentiate when clicked on tab a from tab b. Both the tabs are blue color and so when tab a is active I need to give some other color. A custom style sheet is being used on page on component level. I am unable to fin reference of this style. So other than changing style sheet, is any way to accomplish this. Al's howt check, which all components are attached to this style sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For changing tab folder colors, you can use `PSSTYLEDEF`.

As you are changing grid tabs, use `PSSTYLEDEF` or the style sheet that is associated with the page definition in which the grid is located.

**Note.** The grid tab styles can be set for each grid individually using the grid properties. However, for page tabs, you can set the styles using only the default styles in the application style sheet.

You must access `PSACTIVETAB`, `PSINACTIVETAB`, and any other tab classes that your application uses (for example, `PSLEVEL1GRIDACTIVETAB`).

> ***PSACTIVETAB***

```
     --->For folder tabs, open the `PSACTIVETAB` class by double-clicking the class name.
```

On the Background tab, select the color of the background of the active tab (matching the color of the tab image that you created).
Note: Use the drop-down list box to find the color or browse through the color choices.

> ***PSINACTIVETAB***

Do the same for the `PSINACTIVETAB` class (or any others that you need)

```
    --->For folder tabs by double-clicking the class name and selecting the Background tab.

    --->For grid tabs, access the style class that is associated with the grid tab.
```

As i don't have much rep. to paste image i just linked my study on stylesheet.
Refer it for more style classes
[Grid tab level style classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE2tF.jpg)